# Problem with units in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I'm having problems with the following equation:

```
\[\frac{dT(t)}{dt} =-1^{\circ}F \text{per hour}\]
```

it displays:

[image]

How do I make "per hour" in normal text form rather than italicized?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to load the `amsmath` package to use `\text`.

Comment: You can try `\textrm{per hour}`. Aren't you in a a context where ordinary text is italic?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `siunitx` package to write correctly units. It works in both text and math modes.

Default is to use negative exponents instead of a fraction. You can force the use of a symbol by using the `\SI` command option `per-mode=symbol`. You can also set the behavior for all units with `\sisetup`.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\fahrenheit}{\SIUnitSymbolDegree F}
%\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}


\begin{document}

    \[\frac{dT(t)}{dt} = \SI{-1}{\fahrenheit\per\hour}\]
    \[\frac{dT(t)}{dt} = \SI[per-mode=symbol]{-1}{\fahrenheit\per\hour}\]

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

**Out-of-the-scope advice**

In well formatted maths, the d of derivative should be upright, not slanted. To do so:

```
\[\frac{\mathrm{d}T(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = \SI[per-mode=symbol]{-1}{\fahrenheit\per\hour}\]
```

[image]

Enjoy!

Comment: The “out-of-the-scope advice” is controversial: many mathematicians—and (La)TeX experts—prefer the italicized “d” and advocate its use: for example, so did Knuth himself throughout _The TeXbook_.  The upright “d”, on the oher hand, is common among engineers; as for physicits, I’ve seen, in published books, examples of both uses.  It is a fact, however, that ISO regulations prescribe the upright “d”.

Answer (score 2):

Here there is my simple and fast proposal without to use the correct package `siuntix` package. I have used also to `derivative` package to have an automatic italicized “d”, from the suggestion of very good user @GuM.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{derivative}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\odv{T(t)}{t}&=-1 {}^{\circ} \mathrm{F/h}\\
\odv{T(t)}{t}&=-1 {}^{\circ} \mathrm{F\ h^{-1}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```